# ArcGIS- WebMapCreation Error

Tags: dojo, arcgis

I have created a  exact sample example and when trying to run it . I am getting lots of errors. Can someone show me how to fix this?

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/gp_popuplink.html

here is one of the Error:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied { response={...}, xhr=XMLHttpRequest, code=1012, mor
```

I am also including the entire working code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Create a Web Map</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/css/esri.css">
  <style>
    html,body,#mapDiv,.map.container{
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      height:100%;
    }
    #legendDiv{
      background-color: #fff;
      position: absolute !important;
      z-index: 99;
      top:10px;
      right:20px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script>
  <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11compact/"></script>
  <script>
    var map,
        webmapId = "1a40fa5cc1ab4569b79f45444d728067";

    require([
      "esri/map",
      "esri/arcgis/utils",
      "esri/dijit/Legend",
      "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function (Map, arcgisUtils, Legend) {
        arcgisUtils.createMap(webmapId, "mapDiv").then(function (response) {
        map = response.map;

        var legend = new Legend({
            map: map,
            layerInfos:(arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response))
        }, "legendDiv");

        legend.startup();
    });
    });
  </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
    <div id="legendDiv"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an essential part of configuration. As can be seen in the error you're getting, your esrimap is fetching a bad url. That's because you haven't setup your server as can be seen in the example you're referring to:

```
//This service is for development and testing purposes only. We recommend that you create your own geometry service for use within your applications. 
config.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");
```

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/yIaX1ijqgTTZgw10KW7A?p=preview) a simple stripped down example on Plunker.

```
  var map;
  require([
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/arcgis/utils",
    "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
    "esri/config",
  ], function(
      Map,
      arcgisUtils,
      GeometryService,
      config
  ) {
      config.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");
      config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
      arcgisUtils.createMap("a193c5459e6e4fd99ebf09d893d65cf0", "mapDiv").then(function(response){
         window.map = response.map;
    });
});
```

Comment: Do i have to run my own server ? Can i not use esri for testing their examples?  if I do need to run my own server what do I need to do? is there any doc on setting it up? - Thanks

Comment: No you don't for testing/development purposes. I've edited my example so you can see it works with the URI they've used in their example. But i guess you'll want to since their map already has custom geometries drawn on it. If you want your own map you can set one up at [arcgis.com](http://www.arcgis.com/features/)